# How to map 3 array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try this

```
test1: [1,2,3] //Array in constructor
test2: [4,5,6] //Array in constructor
test3:  [7,8,9] //Array in constructor
```

/

```
const postList = this.state.test1.map((dateList, titleList, storyList) =>
        <p>
            {dateList}
            <br />
            {this.state.test2[titleList]}
            <br />
            {this.state.test3[storyList]}
            <hr />
        </p>

    );
```

and the result show only from array test1 and test2

Comment: Did you try to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map ? `map` takes 3 arguments - `currentValue, index, array`, not 3 arrays

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do but your code is all wrong.  Map will call your lambda three times datelist will take the values (1,2 and 3), titlelist will take the values (0,1 and 2), storyList will take the values ([1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]) respectively.  this.state.test3[[1,2,3]] is nonsense

Comment: Thank guy, I seriously remiss that map() function second parameter is the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of map-function is the [index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). You called it `titleList`. Rename it to `index` and then change your code to:

```
const postList = this.state.test1.map((dateList, index) =>
        <p>
            {dateList}
            <br />
            {this.state.test2[index]}
            <br />
            {this.state.test3[index]}
            <hr />
        </p>

    );
```

Comment: Thank sir, I was be seriously remiss.